# div FadeIn when I'm on page and FadeOut when I scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my website I'd like that a certain div will appear only when that portion of page is displayed and will fadeIn and fadeOut when I scroll.

My code is the following:

**bio.html**

```
<div ng-controller="bioCtrl" id="bio">
    <h1 style="color:white">Here goes my biography</h1>

    <div id="bioContainer" style="display: none">
        <h3>My Name</h3>
        <p>Hi my name is Pluto and here I write some stuff about my bio.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript is the following

**bio.js**

```
angular.module('allApps').controller('bioCtrl', function($scope, $location, $window) {

    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 520) {
            $("#bioContainer").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#bioContainer").stop().fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

this works fine, actually but, as you may see, I said the fadeIn must start when I scroll over 520px.
Now, 520px is fine for my computer's window but if I had a smaller or bigger monitor, it will have a different value so what I want is that the fadeIn starts when I am into the "#bio" section.

Answer (score 2):

Get the top position of `#bio` using `.offset().top` and then just adjust you `if` statement to check if `$(this).scrollTop()` is greater than that.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var fadeHere = $("#bio").offset().top
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > fadeHere) { 
        $("#bioContainer").fadeIn();
    } 
    // . . .
```

This will cause fadeIn when `#bio` gets to top of the window. If you want fadeIn when `#bio` first appears in bottom of window, use

```
var fadeHere = $("#bio").offset().top - $(window).height()
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqwhnkns/

Comment: Thanks, I found out actually the same solution. I just used this little variation `var fadeHere = $("#bio").offset().top - $(window).height()/2`